# Pythonic way to wrap a function using additional arguments and changing the output

Tags: python, wrapper, args, keyword-argument, functools

I am using functions from external librairies (such as *scipy.optimize.minimize*) and for conveniance I have wrapped them up to pre-process and post-process the arguments. I am aware of the *wraps* decorator from *functools* but I can't find a way to use it properly.

Here is basic example of what I do:

```
def wrapper(outer_arg, **inner_arguments):
    inner_arg = prepare_inputs(outer_arg)
    inner_output = inner_function(inner_arg, **inner_arguments)
    outer_output = prepare_outputs(inner_output)
    return outer_output
```

The problem with this is that I loose the docstring from *inner_function* when calling *help* and I do not want to copy all the arguments in the wrapper declaration.
I have tried to add the *wraps* decorator like so:

```
@wraps(inner_function)
def wrapper(outer_arg, **inner_arguments):
    inner_arg = prepare_inputs(outer_arg)
    inner_output = inner_function(inner_arg, **inner_arguments)
    outer_output = prepare_outputs(inner_output)
    return outer_output
```

But then I loose the docstring of *wrapper* when calling *help*.

**Is there a way to write this function that would give the user insight on both the *wrapper* and the *inner_function* (and be able to use autocompletion etc...)** ?

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too. Either `wrapper` has its own docstring, or it imitates `inner_function`. You could _merge_ both docstrings into one, but you can't make one function have two docstrings.

Comment: @deceze I guess I am too greedy. How would you *merge* both doctrings ? Thanks

Comment: Something alongs the lines of `wrapper.__doc__ += '\n' + inner_function.__doc__`.

Comment: This looks like a very good answer to my question actually

Comment: I'm not currently in a position to fully test this out, so… feel free to post an answer when you've shaken the idea down.

Answer (score 0):

Using @deceze idea I built a decorator to format the wrapped function's doctring:

```
def merge_docstrings(other):
    def decorator(func):
        func.__doc__ = f'{func.__doc__}'.format(other.__doc__)
        return func
    return decorator
```

It does format the `wrapper` doctring with the one of `inner_function`
But it doesn't work well when displaying the docstring in PyCharm for example, and obviously you don't get auto-completion with the arguments of `inner_function`. I am not sure how auto-completion work and if it would be possible to achieve what I want.

Comment: The docstring of `func` contains a `{0}` where I want the docstring of `other`to feature. So that's how I managed to do it. I am not very good with strings, laybe this isn't the best way. Would `func.__doc__.format(other.__doc__)` work ?